# How to get tinymce content in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, tinymce

i am trying to get tinymce data but getting tinyMCE undefined error. Here is my code:

```
function savePost( ){ 

    console.log(  jQuery('#wp_tinymce_editor').tinyMCE().getContent() );
}
```

please check

Answer (score 26, accepted):

TinyMCE object/library is the one the responsible for your Editor, so you should use that object to get the content.

You can use the `activeEditor` for that, or if (for some reason) you have the original element that created the editor in a jQuery object, you can use that jQuery object to get the `id` of the original element and use that in order to get the content of the TinyMCE (using the TinyMCE editor).

> Only with jQuery - **You should never use this**

If for some reason you really have to use only jQuery for that (and I really don't understand why), you can use the id of the original element, concatenated with `_ifr` and get the content. Using this option will probably give you don't want, because tinymce add tags to the html that exists in the dom but stripped when calling the `getContent` function.

Here is an example for the 3 options:

```
$('#btn1').click(function() {
    console.log(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent());
});
$('#btn2').click(function() {
    console.log(tinyMCE.editors[$('#ta').attr('id')].getContent());
});
$('#btn3').click(function() {
    alert('You should really NOT use this option');
    console.log($('#ta_ifr')[0].contentDocument.body.innerHTML);
});
```

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/8tdf3q22/

Comment: getContent does () not work for me. But getting from the last one(getting HTML directly from iframe ) works fine. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 6):

Html text editor text code:

```html
<textarea name="description" class="tinymce" id="texteditor"></textarea>
```

You can print TinyMCE text editor code using javascript like this.

```js
var content = tinymce.get("texteditor").getContent();
alert(descriptionFieldTxt);
```

output:

[image]

output with tags
[image]

Now you can print tinymce texteditor value without p tag like this

```js
var content = tinymce.get("texteditor").getContent({format: "text"});
alert(descriptionFieldTxt);
```

This code print text without tags:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea class="tinymce" id="texteditor"></textarea>
```

and in jquery, you can do like this.

```
var content = tinymce.get("texteditor").getContent();
```