# passing text from div to text editor TinyMCE and passing back to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

[image]

HTML to load the text from div below and edit it with TinyMCE editor in popup module and update the text after save button is clicked I tried the code below but it didn't work.

```
<div class="sim-row-header1-slider-left-text sim-row-edit" data-type="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vitae ullamcorper orci. Nullam nulla felis, imperdiet ac sollicitudin et, malesuada sagittis lacus.</div>
```

HTML Popup module for editing the text with text editor

```
<div class="sim-edit" id="sim-edit-text">
<div class="sim-edit-box" style="height:390px;">
<div class="sim-edit-box-title">Edit Text</div>

<div class="sim-edit-box-content">
<div class="sim-edit-box-content-text">Text</div>
<div class="sim-edit-box-content-field"><textarea class="sim-edit-box-content-field-textarea text text-editor"></textarea></div>
</div>
<div class="sim-edit-box-buttons">
<div class="sim-edit-box-buttons-save">Save</div>
<div class="sim-edit-box-buttons-cancel">Cancel</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript for passing data to the text editor and pass it back when save button is clicked.

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: ".text-editor",
    width:      '100%',
    height:     270,
    plugins:    [ "anchor link" ],
    statusbar:  false,
    menubar:    false,
    toolbar:    "link anchor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify",
    rel_list:   [ { title: 'Lightbox', value: 'lightbox' } ]
});

//edit text
if(big_parent.attr("data-type")=='text'){

$("#sim-edit-text .text").val(big_parent.text());
$("#sim-edit-text").fadeIn(500);
$("#sim-edit-text .sim-edit-box").slideDown(500);

$("#sim-edit-text .sim-edit-box-buttons-save").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().parent().fadeOut(500)
  $(this).parent().parent().slideUp(500)

    big_parent.text($("#sim-edit-text .text").val());



    });

}
```

Comment: this cuold help, this  is how to get tinymce content https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39001561/how-to-get-tinymce-content-in-jquery and this is how to set content into tinymce  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780766/setcontent-of-an-textarea-with-tinymce

Answer (score 0):

Once TinyMCE loads on the page the underlying `textarea` is no longer visible on the page.  As you type into TinyMCE you are not actually updating the `textarea` but rather you are typing into an iFrame.

Before you attempt to use JavaScript to interact with the `textarea` you would want to call `triggerSave()` to get TinyMCE to update the underlying `textarea` with the current editor content.  Alternatively you can get TinyMCE's content via its `getContent()` API (https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#getcontent).